# What are the actual new provisions that have outlawed using megaphones in protests or political demonstrations?

Tags: england-and-wales, freedom-of-speech, protest

Newly passed legislation has caused certain political demonstrators to get done for demonstrating with amplified megaphones where they were completely allowed to do so in the past. What specifically are these new statutory provisions?

Comment: What do you mean by "*to get done for demonstrating with amplified megaphones*" Do you mean that activists are now forbidden to use such devices? "Done for" is not, in my experience, usually used with that sort of meaning.Also, can you cite or link to any source that indictes the chane you mention? A news story, perhaps?

Comment: It's a Britishism I suppose.

Comment: https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2021/mar/14/new-anti-protest-bill-raises-profound-concern-human-rights-groups-say

Comment: https://www.thetimes.co.uk/article/e709cf3c-f7e5-11ec-84c1-32e852e780b0?shareToken=d355a364027527977d0e071df6473842

Comment: The Metropolitan police said Bray’s equipment had been seized under section 145 of the 2011 Police Reform Social Responsibility Act, which gives the force power to seize items being used for prohibited activities in Parliament Square. That includes operating amplified sound equipment in the controlled area.

Comment: "Getting done" [for X/Y/Z] in British English means to be caught out by authorities and somehow reprimanded or penalised for doing something which is against the rules or law.

Comment: Thank you foer te clarification.